# Generating a tree based on two lists

Tags: haskell, tree

i'd like to know how to generate a tree based in two lists. The first one representing a pre-order and the second one an in-order one of the wanted tree to be generated, for example:

```
data Tree a = Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf deriving Show
genTree :: [a] -> [a] -> Tree a
genTree [7,9,2] [9,7,2] = 
Branch 7 (Branch 9 Leaf Leaf ) (Branch 2 Leaf Leaf )
```

Any suggestion is accepted, Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**in** and **pre** describes the **position** of the **root** in the sequence. So:

1. the **first** element of `inorder` sequence is the **root**. Then left subtree inorder sequences followed by right subtree's. but we don't know where the right subtree sequence begins.
2. if we can locate the **root** in `preorder` sequence, then the left side is the preorder sequences of the left subtree, right hand is the preorder sequence of the right subtree.

Assume we have a binary tree like this:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
   /  \
  4    5

preorder: 1 2 3 4 5
inorder : 2 1 4 3 5
```

Let's build it back! OK, look at preorder sequence `1 2 3 4 5`. We know 1 is the root.

```
[1] 2 3 4 5
2 [1] 4 3 5
```

`2` is left subtree's inorder sequence. `4 3 5` is right subtree's. And also we have known:

1. left subtree has only *1* node, right has *3* nodes!
2. left subtree preorder sequences aside right's preorder sequence is `2 3 4 5`

as a result, left's preorder is `2`, right's is `3 4 5`.

And the recursive begins. until we have nothing! that is the empty sequence. Then we have met the `Leaf`.

---

Summarized it up, we have the following Haskell code. (This does not handle the incorrect input situation)

```
data Tree a = Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Leaf
            deriving Show
--                 pre    in
genTree :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Tree a
genTree [] [] = Leaf
genTree (root:pre_seq) in_seq = Branch root left right
  where
    (left_in, _:right_in) = break   (== root)        in_seq
    (left_pre, right_pre) = splitAt (length left_in) pre_seq
    left  = genTree left_pre  left_in
    right = genTree right_pre right_in
```

Comment: At a glance, I suspect it doesn't correctly handle trees containing duplicate values

Comment: @luqui yes, that's true, this is just a piece code showing the algorithm. Talking about duplicates, so how to restore a tree with `0 0 0 0... 0` and `0 0 0 0... 0`? That's another question, with type signature `[a]->[a]->[Tree a]`. Duplicates makes us enumerate. But they share the same thoughts IMHO.